# Separate MySQL Server Login File

Tags: php

My supervisor wants me to have a separate MySQL login configuration file, which will then be read and executed by my pages.

He wants it separate so that it is easily changeable.

How would I go about creating it (with separate lines for each of the parts for authentication, i.e. server, username, password, etc) and including it in say, one of my regular pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short simple setup:

dbcredentials.php

```
$db_user = 'fred';
$db_pass = 'flintstone';
$db_name = 'bedrock';
$db_host = 'localhost';
```

db_con.php

```
require_once('dbcredentials.php');
$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass) or die(mysql_error());
```